# Alternative of sigsetjmp() in Shell

Tags: bash, shell, setjmp

I want the work of the script below to continue after the interrupt arrives and until the first successful entry. In C usually used `sigsetjmp()` and `siglonglmp()`. Any alternatives in Shell scripts?
Thanks.

```
i()
{
    echo "Okay ..."
}
trap 'i' INT
read -p "X " X
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to restart the read if SIGINT is raised?

Comment: Yes, I literally mean this one

Comment: When I try your script with an added `echo $X has been read.`, the `echo` is executed and prints what I entered after the interrupt, i. e. it behaves as you desire without further ado.